# Solution of telegraph equation by Laplace transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, wave-equation

I am working through some exercises in the text *Integral Transforms and Their Applications* by Debnath and Bhatta. This exercise comes in Chapter 4 - Applications of Laplace Transforms.

Solve the telegraph equation $$ u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} + 2au_x = 0 $$ subject to the initial conditions $$u(x, 0) = 0, u_t(x, 0) = g(x)$$ where $-\infty < x < \infty$ and $t > 0.$

Let $\mathcal{L}u(x, t) = U(x, s)$ (that is, take the Laplace transform in the time variable). Then after taking transforms the equation becomes $$s^2U - g(x) - c^2U_{xx} + 2asU = 0$$

which can be rearranged to

$$ ((s+a)^2 - a^2)U - c^2U_{xx} = g(x) $$

after some collecting of terms and completing the square. Solving the corresponding homogeneous problem gives the solution

$$U_c = c_1(s)e^{\lambda x} + c_2(s)e^{-\lambda x}$$

where $\lambda = \frac{1}{c} \sqrt{(s+a)^2 - a^2}.$ To obtain the particular solution, we use variation of parameters to arrive at

$$U_p = \frac{1}{2\lambda} \int_0 ^x e^{\lambda(x-t)} g(t) \ dt - \frac{1}{2\lambda} \int_0 ^x e^{-\lambda(x-t)} g(t) \ dt = \int_0 ^x g(t) \sinh(\lambda(x-t)) \ dt. $$

My issue now is that this isn't phrased as a typical boundary value problem, but I expect that the solution $u(x, t)$ should decay to zero as $x \to \pm \infty.$ I am also unsure on how to handle the unknown functions $c_1 (s)$ and $c_2 (s)$. If I assumed this decay, then both $c_1$ and $c_2$ would be the zero function, which I don't believe is correct. Is there a way to proceed with the solution as I've written it?

---

Following Gonçalo's suggestion, I've taken the Fourier transform of the ODE for $U(x, s)$. With $\mathcal{F}(U(x, s)) = \overline{U}(\omega, s),$ we have

$$ -\omega^2 \overline{U}(\omega, s) - \lambda^2 \overline{U}(\omega, s) = \frac{\overline{g}(\omega)}{c^2} $$

which gives

$$ \overline{U}(\omega, s) = -\frac{\overline{g}(\omega)}{c^2(\omega^2 + \lambda^2)}.$$

Using the book's convention of defining the Fourier transform with

$$ \overline{F}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{-i\omega x} F(x) \ dx $$

we arrive at

$$ U(x, s) = -\frac{1}{\lambda c^2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{\lambda |y|} g(x-y) \ dy $$

which is a convolution, but now I'm still at a roadblock.

Comment: Suggestion: solve the ODE for $U$ using Fourier transform. The inversion of the Laplace transform will be simpler.

Comment: @Gonçalo I've arrived at a convolution for the Laplace transform, but am unsure of how to invert it. I've edited to include this attempt.

Comment: I would also do what Goncalo suggested. Likely the inversion of your convolution integral gives a special function. Often you'll get modified bessels $I_k(2\sqrt{x t})$ in these problems. I would look for the inverse transform here: https://books.google.no/books/about/Integrals_and_Series_Inverse_Laplace_tra.html?id=hvfZzgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: Another note: you can still obtain useful information from the Laplace representation. For small $s$ you get the large $t$ behavior, for example. Your kernel becomes $e^{-at/c-|y|}$ I believe.

Comment: @kevinkayaks But is there a known result about inverting a convolution? The usual result is that a convolution gets transformed to a pointwise product, but I'm not sure if the inverse transform of a convolution is a known result.

Comment: There's no result for arbitrary $g$ that I'm aware of. But a solution in terms of an integral is a solution. Not much more can be expected for a boundary condition that's an arbitrary function. I would invert the kernel and leave your result as an integral. You could always evaluate this numerically or analytically for particular $g$

Comment: What I had in mind with my suggestion was, after solving the ODE for $U$, to take first the inverse Laplace transform of $\overline{U}(\omega, s)$, then the inverse of the Fourier transform. This way, the result is given by
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{e^{-at}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{g}(\omega)\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{a^2-\omega^2c^2}\,t)}{\sqrt{a^2-\omega^2c^2}}e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega.
$$

Comment: $$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{b}g(x) \sin(bt) \implies u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} +2au_x = 0 \implies -bg(x) - c^2 g''(x) + \frac{2a}{b} g'(x) = 0.$$ So if $g(x)$ satisfies above differential equation then your solution is $u(x,t) = \frac{1}{b}g(x) \sin(bt)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo would you be open to posting a full solution?

Comment: @SeanRoberson, you did the lion's share. I only gave a suggestion.